# jquery Ajax php array transfer in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery

I have a situation where i'd like one selectbox to change based on the selected option in another selectbox.

html could go:

```
<select name="gender-select" id="gender-select">
    <option value="girls">girls</option>
    <option value="boys">boys</option>
</select>

<select name="names" id="names">
    <option value="">Marie</option>
    <option value="">Rachael</option>
    <option value="">Lis</option>
</select>
```

So all the names would be stored in an SQL database. Lets assume that theres 10 names stored in total.

Then when the "boys" option is selected, the database should look up all the boys names in the database and feed those as options.

I know that i would use AJAX for this, and i have a setup of this that does do a successful request. My problem is that i need to pass the array of names into the function that handles the data, before sending it back to the javascript.

Im doing this in wordpress, and the process im thinking of would go like this (im sure there must be a better way - if not how would this be done? ):

1. php in the template would build an array via a custom loop.
2. javascript would take that array with the parameter of "boys", and on select change pass the array and parameter on to functions.php
3. functions.php would then do its thing, to find all the boys names, and then send those back to javascript,
4. js will then display the new options

To me this seems silly converting php -> js -> php -> js

just to sort an array async.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Why not render out both Name Selects organized by Sex, and then show/hide the appropriate select on change? This will eliminate the need to query the server every time.

Comment: because there would be many more than 2. likely around 50 options in both - obviously my case is not gender/names related - that was just as an example of the problem

Comment: I think then it not only depends on the size of the database table you're querying, but also the kind of usage you would ordinarily expect from the user. Querying the database via AJAX on each change is a viable option, but could get expensive depending on usage. With smaller tables and limited options, you could implement the show/hide functionality I mentioned. With larger tables, you could cache the result of each query to a local Javascript variable so that repeat queries aren't being performed by the server.

Comment: The last option - though arguably more complex - is to query the entire table and parse the results in such a way that the change event just references a local object to grab the pre-processed data, thus eliminating the need for AJAX in the first place. But this could be overkill depending on how the users actually use your form.

Answer (score 2):

Persanally I'm doing this way in every AJAX process in wordpress :

http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

it's very good explained and represents the very safe way to use AJAX in WP.

Comment: already looked at that- but don't quite get how to deal with large arrays.